# why does my custom font implementation not work in pyqt5?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt

i am trying to use a custom font in pyqt5, and after some searching it became clear i had to use QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(). so i implemented it and the file seems to have the right path (i renamed the file and the name in my python changed as well). However i get the standard font when i use this code:

```
Fontdb = QFontDatabase
Fontdb.addApplicationFont("Omega.ttf")

class Centre(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    x1 = int(Centralwidth * 0.08333)
    y1 = int(Centralheight * 0.083333)
    self.setGeometry(int(x1-10), int(y1-10), int(Centralwidth-10), int(Centralheight-10))

  def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 225, 255, 215), 13, Qt.DashLine)))

    x1 = int(Centralwidth * 0.08333)
    y1 = int(Centralheight * 0.083333)
    dottedcircle = QRectF(x1, y1, 640, 640)
    Arc1 = dottedcircle.adjusted(20, 20, -20, -20)
    Arc2 = dottedcircle.adjusted(25, 25, -25, -25)
    Arc3 = dottedcircle.adjusted(45, 45, -45, -45)
    Arc4 = dottedcircle.adjusted(40, 40, -40, -40)
    Arc5 = dottedcircle.adjusted(50, 50, -50, -50)
    painter.drawEllipse(dottedcircle)

    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 175, 255, 200), 40)))
    painter.drawArc(Arc1, 1440, 3200)
    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 150, 230, 190), 30)))
    painter.drawArc(Arc2, 5120, 1440)
    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 175, 230, 150), 25)))
    painter.drawArc(Arc3, 2240, 1600)
    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 180, 255, 140), 20)))
    painter.drawArc(Arc4, 4480, 1520)
    painter.setPen((QPen(QColor(50, 160, 255, 210), 50)))
    painter.drawArc(Arc5, 800, 900)
    painter.drawArc(Arc5, 3680, 900)

    painter.setFont(QFont("Omega", 60))
    painter.drawText(dottedcircle, Qt.AlignCenter, "A.G.O.S.")



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Centre()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please always try to keep your examples **minimal**. There's no need for all the painting functions used before `drawText`, they are just a distraction. In fact, there is no need for custom painting at all, as a simple QLabel with `setFont()` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to ensure that the font *is* correctly loaded, and that can be easily checked by showing the result of `addApplicationFont()`.

```
fontId = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Omega.ttf")
if fontId < 0:
    print('font not loaded')
```

Then, the argument for the QFont constructor is **not** the file name, but the font family. You can check them by using the previously returned font id with [`applicationFontFamilies`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#applicationFontFamilies) using the font id returned by `addApplicationFont()`:

```
families = QtGui.QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(fontId)
font = QtGui.QFont(families[0])
```

Finally, `addApplicationFont` should *always* be called **after** the instance of QApplication is created.